# Why can't reflection access the _invocationList/_invocationCount fields in a MulticastDelegate variable?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates

I'm typing all this in the immediate window while sitting on a breakpoint:

```
typeof(MulticastDelegate).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
{System.Reflection.FieldInfo[6]}
    [0]: {System.Object _invocationList}
    [1]: {IntPtr _invocationCount}
    [2]: {System.Object _target}
    [3]: {System.Object _methodBase}
    [4]: {IntPtr _methodPtr}
    [5]: {IntPtr _methodPtrAux}
```

Looks good, right? But let's try it with an actual delegate variable of type `EventHandler` (that has two registered listeners, obtained by reflecting over an object with an event of that type):

```
l.GetType().Name
"EventHandler"
l is MulticastDelegate
true
l.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
{System.Reflection.FieldInfo[4]}
    [0]: {System.Object _target}
    [1]: {System.Object _methodBase}
    [2]: {IntPtr _methodPtr}
    [3]: {IntPtr _methodPtrAux}
```

And for good measure:

```
((MulticastDelegate)l).GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
{System.Reflection.FieldInfo[4]}
    [0]: {System.Object _target}
    [1]: {System.Object _methodBase}
    [2]: {IntPtr _methodPtr}
    [3]: {IntPtr _methodPtrAux}
```

Why can't I access `_invocationList` or `_invocationCount` by reflecting on the variable when I can by reflecting on `MulticastDelegate` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me clear a misunderstanding:

```
((MulticastDelegate)l).GetType()
```

If `l` is a `MulticastDelegate` or any derivate, this line is equivalent to:

```
l.GetType()
```

As `GetType` will retrieve the runtime type of the reference.

---

Now, your real issue doesn't have much to do with delegates, but with the way reflection works in general.

When you retrieve the fields of a given type, and you use `NonPublic`, the private fields of the **relfected type** will be returned, but *not* the fields of any type up in the type hierarchy. The *reflected type* is the type you call `GetFields` on.

The reason for this behavior is that subtypes may declare private fields having the same name than private fields in supertypes. This is a must-have, since subtypes can't be expected to know what *private* members of any other class are, including their supertype. You can *always* "redeclare" private members.

Try it with the following code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(B).GetFields(flags).Length);
    }
}

public class A
{
    private int _foo;
}

public class B : A
{
    private int _bar;
}
```

The output value is `1`.

---

Note that [`BindingFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) has a value `FlattenHierarchy` which does the following:

> Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy should be returned. Private static members in inherited classes are not returned. Static members include fields, methods, events, and properties. Nested types are not returned.

But it won't help you there. If you want to list all private fields, you'll have to go up the type hierarchy manually.

Comment: Looks like that's correct. I was getting hung up on the fact that events are are a kind of smokescreen for delegates, but I guess it's as simple as inheritance.

Comment: The funny thing is that your code shows that the CLI *seems to violate*  ECMA-335, secion II.14.6, which states: *"Delegates shall be declared sealed, and the **only members** a delegate shall have are either the first two or all four methods as specified here"* (emphasis mine). Let's call it sloppy spec wording, as it's clear there *are* other members there (except they're private) - they sould've said *"methods"* or "*public members"* instead of just *"members"*.